# How to combine database files and python file to from an executable file?

Tags: python, mysql, database, class, pyinstaller

I have created a software in python using MYSQL as a database. The software is now complete and I want to bundle up all the files to a single (.exe) file so that when the user installs it the database files would come to work without any hindrance.

The software comprises of a single python file containing code in it. Rest 7 files are the SQL text files that I exported from the database.

I am not able to bundle up all the files into an executable installer file.

I have tried using pyinstaller but it only creates a folder with python file. The database files are not being used in it.